# Reviewer makes an obvious and serious mistake and paper is rejected

Tags: journals, peer-review

Long story short: Submitted a paper to a very respectable (but not TOP) journal in the TCS community. Received 2 reviews. The one was alright, not extremely enthusiastic but a decent review.

The problem is with the 2nd one: The reviewer failed in the most obvious way to even understand the statement of the problem, and said that "I cannot convince myself that the paper is correct". The misunderstanding is on the definition of the problem.

for the TCS people: its a standard resource allocation problem where we want to optimize some objective function. The reviewer's objection is that *if we assign the same item multiple times to different users we could achieve a very different objective value thus the analysis on its bounds we give could not possibly be correct!*

This does not any make sense since on the definition it is said explicitly that each item must be assigned once. In any case, it's the most standard definition of a very well known resource allocation problem!

Anyway, after the rejection of the paper based on the above reason, I contacted the Editor in Chief of the journal, asking for a 3rd reviewer to resolve the issue (I was not offensive to the 2nd R). The EiC responded immediately saying that a 3rd R could indeed resolve the issue but there is nothing the EiC could do because the handling editor communicated to the EiC that the Com. Editor trusts the expertise of the reviewers, and thus the rejection decision is irrevocable.

I want to ask:

- How normal is this situation? We are talking about an old and very well respected TCS journal, not some hocus pocus unknown journal.
- Is there any safety net for such kind of obvious mis-managed cases?
- Any particular advice for the incident? I am not very interested in the obvious "deal with it, it happens" answer. But observe that I am in a point of my career that an extra journal publication could mean a lot, since I am trying to find a permanent position and I cannot wait another year for this paper to go through such a process.

***Note:*** I see few people misunderstood my comment. My comment is not targeted to the reviewer who might have made an honest mistake. It happens and I do not blame her/him. My point is mainly on the way the journal handled the situation,  even when the very serious and very easy mistake was brought up to their attention. I was mainly interested if such a reason is valid for straight rejection (usually there is some revision needed which we have the chance to explain to the reviewer and the editor where they have been mistaken), and what to do when this happens. As mentioned again, I do not have 30 journal papers so that I could say this won't make any impact in my CV. I am applying for permanent positions and a +1 (very good) journal might make some difference. Thus my main question: is there any *safety net* that prevent non-professional *editors* make such unjustified and arbitrary decisions with such huge impact on us? And how this affect *only* us as authors? Is there any way to make journals (in general) act more professionally (without making a war against them): sadly, from the comments below, I guess not, besides boycotting the journal, but they couldn't care less.

Comment: Regarding your last question: why not try a reputable conference?

Comment: Sure, that's an option (although I'm bigger fan of journals, maybe my math genes are kicking to that direction)

Comment: _Is there any safety net for such kind of obvious mis-managed cases?_ The editor-in-chief _is_ the safety net. If he/she aren't doing their job, it sounds like you (and the journal) are out of luck.

Comment: @DanRomik It is so sad that in a scientific world one should rely on luck to have a decent paper accepted. But I agree nevertheless.

Comment: @PsySp The way I like to think of it is: "writing a good paper is getting a ticket to the lottery".

Comment: This is normal.  I just had a paper rejected for the same reason.  I got a reviewer who was math adverse and made up things to reject the paper.  I always wonder how some people manage to consistently get into top journals without suffering such incidents.  Maybe this type of incident only happens to mere mortals?

Comment: For such incidents in the context of seminal papers, see https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/~qsheng/papers/computer.pdf

Comment: @DanRomik The EiC is the safety net in theory.  In practice, given the workload and understanding the fact that authors' are usually not happy after receiving a review, they will rarely act.  Also, they may not be in your technical area and no matter how how you argue 1+1 is two when the reviewer said is 3 will fall on deaf ears.

Comment: "I am not very interested in the obvious "deal with it, it happens" answer": then it looks like the answer that will make you happy will not be in phase with reality. You appealed, it didn't work out, that's about it. We all had papers rejected for reasons we did not approve of, now your question is how to get the best from a bad situation. Moving forward instead of wasting energy and possibly reputation by overplaying repeted appeals, and clarify the paper to make the error of the second referee  even less likely to occur to reader are the two advice you need, and they've been given.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner You are right. My point is to see if this kind of situation is not very unlikely and possible ways to deal with it. Answers like "oh well, it happens", realistic as they might be, they are not really constructive. For me the story with this journal is considered closed. As you say, it did not work out, but my point was not to make it work out no matter what, just to see different points/opinions or maybe some advise on something that I might have missed out.

Comment: _I see few people misunderstood my comment._ No, people understood your question perfectly well. In my opinion, it is you who are refusing to understand the answers that have been offered to you, which are telling you the honest truth that you have no recourse other than to move on and submit your paper to a different journal. Sorry if it's not what you were hoping to hear. Good luck!

Comment: @DanRomik It might very well be true, but I was referring to comments that imply that if the reviewer got it wrong, then there _must_ be something wrong with the paper (which is not the case, and it is verified and this is not even the point! reviewers make mistakes). Anyway,  since I do not have editorial experience, I was interested to see what other people have to say about similar situations and how it works inside the editorial of a journal. If there is nothing we can do, then so be it, fingers crossed for the next submission. Thanks for your comments nevertheless

Comment: @DanRomik Actually, the main source of my frustration comes from the fact that I try to make thorough reviews to every request I get (and I get multiple). When I receive as an author an unprofessional answer, common as it may apparently be, it makes me loose all my motivation to try and make good and _helpful_ reviews. It works cyclically. I am really afraid that at some point I will be like "Oh I don't care, it doesn't _seem_ ok to me, I will reject it without further thinking, if no one cares to spend 5 seconds on my paper, why would I". I am really terrified on such prospect.

Comment: @PsySp Your paper may be correct but still confusingly written. If the reviewer misunderstood it, chances are decent that if it were published, other readers would too.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Maybe. But i find it perfectly clear. My co-authors too. Two other experts in the field also. As well as three other colleagues who read it (at least on the definition part, not the technical content). Still, there is a non-zero possibility that all of us are completely wrong (or have a blind spot) and the reviewer is right.

Comment: @PsySp It's easier to understand something you wrote yourself, though. Can you have someone less expert (though still reasonably knowledgable in your field) read it? IME experts can have a a harder time spotting unclear writing because they're better equipped to see around/past it.

Answer (score 20):

It is pretty normal for a reviewer not to get the gist of your article and then the article gets rejected. I find that the best way to deal with that is to remember that the reviewers are reading the article more carefully than the future readers. So if they don't get what I want to write, the future readers are surely not going to get what I want to write.

Sometimes reviewers are just wrong: they are humans too and typically do this with a limited time budget (a larger time budget than future readers will want to spent on your article, but still pretty small). That is bad luck. Just improve what needs improving and submit your article to the next journal.

Comment: Thanks. But that is not quite the answer that I need (so also last part of my question) for several reasons. It is not about the gist of the article but about the basic definition (even in abstract is mentioned!)The definition is clear about the specifications, it couldn't made simpler. The fact that R doesn't understand a very simple definition, means that R is far from expert. I wonder why respectable journals consult such obviously under-qualified  reviewers, and how can we avoid such cases which have potentially high impact on our current situation (job market)

Comment: BTW that's the Editor's job: to filter out obviously bad reviews and not base her/his opinion on flawed ones. After all, the editor is not anonymous and s/he makes big damage to her/his reputation as things turn out.

Comment: I understand your frustration, I have felt the same way you have many times. But giving in to that will only make your life in academia miserable. Moreover, often the reviewers don't look so dumb anymore after a good night sleep. Remember that we are deeply invested in our own articles, and it is easy to loose sight of how the article looks to readers. So I suggest you focus some time on another project, and look at the reviews again after you have calmed down.

Comment: @PsySp Until you haven't made reviewing mistake yourself, you will be upset about this. But, at some point in the future in a scientific career, you are likely to do someone injustice in your review, either reject a deserving paper or accept an undeserving one - because you are overloaded, overestimated your expertise, were just tired or whatever; and will understand that mistakes, unavoidably, do happen. In my opinion, it is the mistake of the editor here, rather than the reviewer. FYI, we once submitted to a top(!) journal and got very flawed reviews with factual mistakes and no recourse.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs My frustration (believe me, it's very mild) is mainly towards the editor (I thought it was apparent from my question). I did not actually blame the reviewer, no matter how obviously under-qualified is, but the editor for (1) selecting this R, (2) trusting him and (3) not even reading my response (if s/he did, it would be apparent in a minute that there is something very funny is going on)

Comment: @MaartenBuis I understand but a reviewer that replies "why you don't assign your items/jobs multiple times to achieve a different objective function value" is clearly "dumb" when the definition explicitly says that each job/item is allocated exactly once!

Comment: If you follow Maarten Buis' advice, then regarding your comment "*The definition is clear about the specifications, it couldn't made simpler*", I suggest including a short follow-up statement along the lines of "Note that because we're assuming ..." that explicitly addresses the 2nd reviewer's concerns.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro The definition, as it is, does not allow any room for misunderstanding. 
I explained it to both the handling editor and to the Editor in Chief the situation, and I asked a 3rd reviewer to resolve the issue. The handling editor refused to do so because "s/he trusted the expertise of the 2nd R". Obviously, s/he didn't even read my reply (or, even worse, s/he was the 2nd R!)

Comment: Don't assume bad intend. Maybe the 2nd reviewer is really trustworthy and maybe (s)he made an error, or maybe you were not as clear as you think. If you want to improve your article, you will have to seriously consider the second option.

Comment: @PsySp I would provide an informal definition next to the formal one.  Maybe provide a toy example to illustrate what the definition means.  The reviewer is simply telling you that part is easily overlooked, and once that happens, the paper falls apart, as illustrated by his/her unfair review.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Well, the problem is both formally and informally introduced (in the abstract). On the other hand, no toy example is given. I am not sure, do we give also toy examples for MaxCut, and 3Sat as well? It's a standard resource allocation problem. Besides of that, even if the reviewer failed to understand the _abstract_, I think this is _hardly_ a reason to reject the paper and stick to the flawed opinion (this is for the editors). Anyway, the comment is mostly for the editors, and how they didn't care and not about the reviewer.

Comment: @PsySp I understand.  One shouldn't need to mention MaxCut/3Sat.  But a toy example may allow a future reviewer to linger longer at the definition  and prevent this from happening again.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus You are right. But at some point this should have to stop (I mean, what kind of things we need to define)? One time in another paper, I formally defined the class FP^#P and the reviewer reacted "oh that's obvious to the reader, remove the definition", so it's hard to guess what is needed in every case.

Comment: @PsySp Yes, I agree.  As part of writing, we need to make some assumptions about the reader's background knowledge.  However, I have never had a paper rejected because i presented too much info; more often, reviewers appreciate it because the basics provide some comfort to the reader as opposed wading through unfamiliar definitions and concepts.

Comment: @PsySp Referring to the fact that it is clearly explained in the abstract misses the point. A paper needs to be completely understandable without the abstract, which is only meant to be the thing you read to see if you want to read the rest of the paper. Nothing should be included only in the abstract.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am not sure I agree with your comment. In my field, the majority (if not the absolute majority) of the papers give a high level definition of the problem in the abstract, and then it is formally defined in the main body of the paper. This is especially true for problems which are simple to define. And that's how you judge if you want to read the paper (because the problem might have a name that is not familiar to you). And I never wrote it's defined _only_ in the abstract.

Answer (score 5):

This happens all the time. I have sometimes raised it with the editor. Doing so has always been a waste of time. The best thing you can do is move on.

I have had a reviewer say it would be good if they had done X, but since they haven't, reject it. Except that we had done X. I got absolutely nowhere. This was at a very prestigious journal.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any safety net for such kind of obvious mis-managed cases?

Well, if there is a Board of Editors you could write to them individually explaining exactly how (in your opinion) the Editor-in-chief has not dealt adequately with your concerns. (I have had it done to me, and had to justify my actions to the members of the Board, coughing up all the correspondence and paperwork. Happily the Board agreed everything had been properly dealt with; but if things had gone wrong I would have expected to be told off to get things sorted, pronto.)

Comment: I am not sure if it's mostly the EiC fault here (although I do not know about editorials). S/he was willing to help (admitted that a 3rd reviewer would resolve the issue) but s/he probably did not want to go against the handling editor's _strict_ recommendation. Certainly, in the whole process, the one that I blame the least is the reviewer. Also, I am not sure there was any obvious mistakes _in the process_, besides blindly trusting an obviously flawed review, even after I brought to their attention the simple mistake.

Comment: If a paper is rejected on the grounds of a fundamentally flawed report, and the editors are unwilling to review their rejection on the basis of the flawed report, then the journal's editors need to review their protocols.

Comment: I think this advice is misguided. Following it would probably not get a better outcome than the OP wasting valuable time, and could possibly make him look bad to the board, which is not a good idea in general and especially for a non-tenured colleague.